# How can I make my parallax landing page responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, parallax

I am creating my website but I am new to web development.
I created a parallax landing page following the youtube tutorial below but I can't make my site responsive... Everything gets distorted, images get cut, etc...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgk_2d4lhm8

I know I have to use media queries, I used them to make my navbar responsive. But when it comes to doing the responsive with images (and especially background images) I can't do it at all.
Can you please tell me how to do it?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site to watch a YouTube video just to understand your question. Plus, that doesn't tell us what _your_ code does. It just tells us what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS I used for my own paralax website. It has 3 background pictures that's reused 4 times. I used 100% in height and therefor I could use background-size cover to have the image use all the space it needed. I also used the position center to have the middle of the image always showing.

Hope this helps.

```
.pic1, .pic2, .pic3{
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.80;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    
    .pic1{
        background-image: url(./images/OnePiece1.jpg);
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```